# call http rquest from beanshell processor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to call a series of http Request from a for loop from Beanshell processor in jmeter.

```
for (String fName : FNameArray) 
         {
            System.out.println(fName);

            if (dict.get(fName) != null) 
            {
                String dicValue = dict.get(fName).toString();
                String sr = dicValue.substring(dicValue.indexOf('=') + 1);
                String id = sr.substring(sr.indexOf('=') + 1);
                String pval = sr.substring(0, (sr.indexOf('=') - 3));
                String email = id.replace("%40", "@");

                System.out.println(id);
                System.out.println(email);
                System.out.println(pval);

                // from here i have to call http request and pass the pval, id and email to that http request
            }
        }
```

From the above code, i have to pass pval, id and email to the 1st http request and then the next http request and so on.
but this pval, id and email are passing from a for loop.
how can i acheive this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following option:

1. Amend your code as follows:

   ```
   for (String fName : FNameArray) {
       int counter = 1;
       System.out.println(fName);

       if (dict.get(fName) != null) {
           String dicValue = dict.get(fName).toString();
           String sr = dicValue.substring(dicValue.indexOf('=') + 1);
           String id = sr.substring(sr.indexOf('=') + 1);
           String pval = sr.substring(0, (sr.indexOf('=') - 3));
           String email = id.replace("%40", "@");

           System.out.println(id);
           System.out.println(email);
           System.out.println(pval);
           vars.put("id_" + counter, id);
           vars.put("email_" + counter, email);
           vars.put("pval_" + counter, pval);
           counter++;

           // from here i have to call http request and pass the pval, id and email to that http request
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after Beanshell Test Element and configure it as follows:

   - Input variable prefix: `id`
   - Output variable name: `current_id`
   - Add "_" before number: checked
   - other fields - blank
3. Add [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) Test Element as a child of the ForEach Controller and configure it like:

   - Start: `1`
   - Increment: `1`
   - Reference Name: `counter`
4. Add [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) after counter and use the following references:

   - "id" - `${current_id}`
   - "email" - `${__V(email_${counter})}`
   - "pval" - `${__V(pval_${counter})}`

   where required.

---

Alternative option is use [Apache HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/quickstart.html) libraries (JMeter is built on top of them so they're available), see above link for quick start and examples. But in that case I would strongly recommend to use [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) instead of Beanshell.